# SQLAlchemy+Flask Many to one relationship

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I am using Flask + SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL with two tables.
Table with users and a table with goals (what a user want to achieve).

**models.py:**

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(Text)
    email = Column(String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(255))
    # A user can only have one goal at a time
    goal_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('goals.id'))
    goal = relationship("Goal", back_populates="user")

class Goal(Base):
    """ Goals: Health, Fitness, Wealth, etc. """
    __tablename__ = 'goals'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80), unique=True)
    description = Column(String(255))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="goal", uselist=False)
```

A user can only have one goal at a time. In my test case I first populate the table Goal with:

**tests.py:**

```
for goal in ["Health", "Fitness", "Wealth"]:
    session.add(Goal(name=goal))
```

And then I want to be able to populate 3 users each with a different goal. What is the correct way of achieving this ?

Trying (simplified code):

```
user = User()
goal = Goal()
user.goal.append(goal)
```

gives me:

> ```
>   user.goal.append(goal)
> ```
>
> E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining goal as `uselist=False` which means it is not being stored as an array. You only need to do `user.goal = goal` instead of `append` since it is not stored as a list.

So instead of

```
user = User()
goal = Goal()
user.goal.append(goal)
```

do this:

```
user.goal = goal
```

Comment: Indeed I missed the point of uselist=False. So now it's fine. However regarding the relationship. Are you sure about that ? `I based the relationship definition on http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html (See: Many To One, Bidirectional behavior..)

Comment: ah yes, my mistake I am used to using `backref` and not `back_populates`. I will update my answer